# Button Not Receiving the OnCLick event

Tags: android, android-layout

I found a weird issue with the below layout

```
<LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_right"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I added click listener like below :

```
  mViewDataBinding.btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) { //show toast}
});
```

But when I tap on the image view the toast doesnt show but when I use the below layout it works as expected

```
 <LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
        android:id="@+id/btn_prev"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tab_bankd_selected" />

        <TextView
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="previous"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I click on the  text view it works . Can some one please tell me what I am missing and what should I do to make it work . The reasone I am using  such a layout is because i am  using SVG images . I already tried making the button clickable:true . The other thing I fail to under stand is how come `TextView` in place of Button is able to wok . Even though button extends `TextView` . Please help

Comment: Your question is not quite clear.

Comment: at first set `Button id`

Comment: Add this properties in LinearLayout in xml layout android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

Comment: set button id : android:id="@+id/your_id"

Comment: btn_next is the id of the linear layout which contains the button . I am using the data binding library in place of findViewById   . https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html . You can even try with normal method of findViewById  . It wont work

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows `mViewDataBinding.btnNext`, but there is no ID assigned to your button... it is not clear how you are getting its reference in `mViewDataBinding.btnNext`. Probably that's where the problem is.

You can probably try to add an ID and get its reference in your code with `findViewById()`, else you can define a method that needs to be called on click of your button in the layout itself with the use of `android:onClick` attribute.

Both the ways are explained below with sample code:

- `onClick` attribute:

  XML:

  ```
  <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
      android:text="Test" />
  ```

  Java (in the `Activity` that this layout is inflated in):

  ```
  public void onButtonClicked(View view) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  ```
- `setOnClickListener()` attribute:

  XML:

  ```
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_test"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
      android:text="Test" />
  ```

  Java (probably in the `onCreate()` of the `Activity` that this layout is inflated in):

  ```
  findViewById(R.id.btn_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: btn_next is the id of the linear layout which contains the button . I am using the data binding library in place of findViewById   . https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html . You can even try with normal method of findViewById  . It wont work

Comment: Did you try cleaning the project and building again? :P Sometimes it helps.

Comment: Yes many times . The issue was that the Button view consumes the onClick event in that region . It seems that Button has an implicit onClick defined .